# Pagination/Lazyloading with Firebase Database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to load 20 items from firebase database initially and as soon as a user scrolls down, 20 more items should be loaded. I thought I could use [startAt](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#startat)/[endAt](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#endat) methods for that but that doesn't work that way. can somebody point me in the right direction?

```
constructor() {
    this.state = {
      startAt: 0,
      endAt: 20,
    };
  }

retrieveData(startAt, endAt) {

const ref = firebase.database().ref().child('clubs').startAt(startAt).endAt(endAt);
ref.on('value', gotData, errorData);

function gotData(data) {
  
// do some stuff with received data

  that.setState({
    startAt: endAt + 1,
    endAt: endAt + endAt
  });
}

function errorData(error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have worked with databases where query results can be based on an offset: a numerical value you pass in of how many items to skip.

Firebase queries don't work with such offsets, but instead are based on the concept of a cursor - or an anchor item. To get a page of results, you must know at what item (the anchor) to start, and how many items to return.

In your code that means that instead of a count of the number of items to skip, you need to keep track of the node where to start. Specifically you need to know the key and whatever property you sorted on. Since you're not sorting on anything, you just need the key.

To get the first page of items, do something like this:

```
let query = firebase.database().ref().child('clubs').orderByKey().limitToFirst(20);
var lastSeenKey;
ref.on('value', gotData, errorData);

function gotData(data) {
  data.forEach((snapshot) => {
    lastSeenKey = snapshot.key;
  })
  ...
}
```

So the changes above are:

1. We explicitly order the query by key, which ensures the server knows how to order the data - and is key to being able to consistently paginate.
2. We then limit to 20 items by calling `limitToFirst(20)`.
3. Finally, we keep track of the last key in the results (our anchor), so that we can use that as the starting point future queries.

Then when you're ready for getting the next page, you'd do:

```
let query = firebase.database().ref().child('clubs').orderByKey().startAt(lastSeenKey).limitToFirst(21);
```

So now we:

- Start at the last key we've previously seen (our anchor item).
- Retrieve 21 instead of 20 items, since we've already shown the anchor item on the previous page.

This topic has been covered quite regularly before, so I recommend also checking out some of the answers to other [questions about pagination on Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D+pagination).

Comment: wow, thank you @Frank van Puffelen for taking the time to answer my question!! this is super helpful and much appreciated! 